# Возможно ли, что TreeSet equals HashSet, но не наоборот HashSet equals TreeSet?

Tags: java, коллекции, hashset, treeset

Вопрос на собеседовании, который сильно меня озадачил: возможно ли, что `TreeSet` equals `HashSet`, но не наоборот `HashSet` equals `TreeSet`? Я ответил "нет", но это был неправильный ответ. Правильный ответ: "да".

Как такое вообще возможно?

---

<sup>Свободный перевод вопроса: [«Is it possible that TreeSet equals HashSet but not HashSet equals TreeSet»](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62477034/11141611).</sup>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**ДА**, в некоторых случаях такое возможно: `TreeSet` может быть равен `HashSet`, но не наоборот. Пример:

```java
TreeSet<String> treeSet = new TreeSet<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
HashSet<String> hashSet = new HashSet<>();
treeSet.addAll(List.of("A", "b"));
hashSet.addAll(List.of("A", "B"));
System.out.println(hashSet.equals(treeSet)); // false
System.out.println(treeSet.equals(hashSet)); // true
```

Причина в том, что [TreeSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) использует [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) для сравнения объектов, а [HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) использует `hashCode`.

---

<sup>При формировании ответа использовался [ответ на вопрос «Is it possible that TreeSet equals HashSet but not HashSet equals TreeSet»](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62477121/11141611) от участника [@aniket-sahrawat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6099347/aniket-sahrawat).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

**НЕТ**, такое невозможно без нарушения основного контракта [equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) класса `Object`, одним из условий которого является *симметричность*, т. е. `x.equals(y)` тогда и только тогда, когда `y.equals(x)`.

**НО**, классы `TreeSet` и `HashSet` по-разному реализуют контракт [equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) интерфейса `Set`, который требует среди прочего, чтобы каждый элемент передаваемого набора содержался в текущем наборе. Для определения вхождения элемента в набор вызывается метод `contains`, который для класса [TreeSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) использует `Comparator`, а для класса [HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) использует `hashCode`.

В итоге:

**ДА**, в некоторых случаях такое возможно.